# what is the relationship between spatial resolution of the image and size of the CNN architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, resolution

I am working on different spatial resolutions of the image and thought to implement CNN architecture for each spatial resolution as resizing images affect the object details. Is there any particular relationship that can quantitatively explained between size of the network and spatial resolution of the image?

Comment: Not sure if there is a direct relation between the size of the network with the resolution of the image. Not sure how much this helps but, in case of detection, check out how SSD is different than YOLO, where it handles aspect ratios and scales. Maybe, see if any network architecture convolutionalizes the input layer to handle multiple resolutions.

Comment: Also look into the [receptive field](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv) of the network. This is related to the size of the model and the size of the inputs (spatial resolution in this case).

Answer (score 1):

There is a relationship between network size and input resolution, though it is a bit indirect. Increases in network size (i.e number of channels and the depth of the network) and input resolution are both computationally taxing. A recent paper proposes [EfficientNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11946) which parameterizes channel number, depth, and input resolution by a single parameter.

In essence, if you only have so much compute power to spend, you must choose how to distribute it over kernel size, depth, and resolution. Required compute power is linearly proportional to depth, each of the input side lengths, and the square of channel number.

Answer (score 0):

An image input is represent as H x W x C where H , W and C are height, width and channel respectively. The size of your convolutional network i.e. (number of parameters) is only dependent on the number and size of convolutional layers you have. Each convolutional layer will add **(Hk * Wk * Cin + 1) * Cout** parameters where Hk and Wk are height and width of the convolutional kernel, Cin the input channels and Cout the output channels.

The input image can only really affect the first convolutional layer. Even then, its spatial dimension will not have an impact on the layer. But the number of channels will.

Consider the following example:

I have a 3 layer CNN consisting of two 3 x 3 convs and one 1 x 1 convs constructed as follows:

**Input (H x W x 3) -> Conv1 (3 x 3 x 3) -> Conv2 (3 x 3 x 5) -> Conv3 (1 x 1 x 7)**

***Weights of first conv layer***:

Hk = 3, Wk = 3, Cin = 3, Cout = 3

Number of parameters in 1st layer = (Hk * Wk * Cin + 1) * Cout = (3*3*3 + 1)*3 = 84 parameters

***Weights of second conv layer***:

Hk = 3, Wk = 3, Cin = 3, Cout = 5

Number of parameters in 2nd layer = (Hk * Wk * Cin + 1) * Cout = (3*3*3 + 1)*5 = 140 parameters

***Weights of third conv layer***:

Hk = 1, Wk = 1, Cin = 5, Cout = 7

Number of parameters in 3rd layer = (Hk * Wk * Cin + 1) * Cout = (1*1*5 + 1)*7 = 42 parameters

Total number of parameters in the network = 84 + 42 + 140 = **266 parameters**.

As you can see, the spatial dims of the input image (H x W) doesn't affect the size of the network but **the number of channels of the image** does.

Comment: The reason i think the `H` and `W` affect the number of of layers of the network is if design a network for `56x56x3` images will have 5 conv layer with `3x3` filters and padding 1 for first four layer. Similary, for `28x28x3` images will have 4 conv layers.

Comment: Your question was about whether spatial dimensions affects the size of the network. I illustrated that it doesn't. It seems to me like you're talking about **size of output feature map** . From your example it looks like you're trying to get an output feature map of a particular size regardless of input image shape. This **will** depend on the size of the input but it wasn't your original question. Given a network , your input has to be resized to a consistent size to get consistent output.

Comment: You can refer the convolution operation documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv2d) to understand how input dim affects the shape of the convolution output.

You shouldn't change your architecture according to your image. It should actually be the other way around. Resize the image to a standard size to produce a consistent output.

Comment: thanks for the answer but my question was related to spatial resolution as i already mentioned about resizing the image affects the quality of the image in my applications so i am not doing resizing from 512x512 pixel to 56x56 pixel image.

Comment: Assuming your images come in different size and you cannot resize them, your only option is to design specific networks for them. But the network size is dependent on the number of layers that you use. The number of layers are designed by you to get image features in a certain shape to produce an output. So to answer your question, there is no quantitative relationship between input image dimensions and size of the network because the network was designed by you for your application. It depends on the number of conv layers, kernel shapes of those layers etc.

Comment: Usually the images would be downsampled by a pooling layer or some other pre-processing, the number of parameters on the first layer could change dramatically depending on the stride size (called padding above), in terms of standard CNN architectures this is a good summary paper for info about CNN architectures  https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.3531 otherwise the above answer holds for a 3 layer nn with stride 1 and no pre-processing